# How to summarise a column in a grouped tibble into a list of unique values

Tags: r, tidyverse, aggregate

Suppose I run the following code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble::tribble(
          ~name,       ~fruit,
          "dan",      "apple",
          "dan",      "apple",
          "dan",     "banana",
       "george",     "banana",
       "george", "watermelon",
       "george",     "banana",
       "lauren",       "kiwi",
       "lauren",       "kiwi",
       "lauren",       "kiwi"
       )

tbl %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(fruits = unique(list(fruit)))
```

This is the table I get:

[image]

Why is it still displaying non-unique fruits in each list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
tbl %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(fruits = unique(list(fruit)))
```

to

```
tbl %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(fruits = list(unique(fruit)))
```

---

Output:

| name | fruits |
| --- | --- |
| dan | apple , banana |
| george | banana , watermelon |
| lauren | kiwi |